# Symfony2 - "This-> Forward" Pointing to external folder

Tags: symfony, forward

I need to find the way to make a forward to a controller located in an external folder to the driver of the bundle.

I have tried to do it in different ways but none made ​​it to that driver.

```
$response = $this->forward
('MiBundle/Api/Subfolder/Controller/Test::index');
return $response;
```

Example:

```
MyBundle
 -Api
   -Subfolder
     -Controller 
       -TestController.php (Forward Target)
 -Controller
 -Entity
 -Form
 -Resources
 -Security
 -Services
 -Tests
```

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think of folders and not an URL as defined by Symfony2?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the full path, and so here:

```
$response = $this->forward('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:fancy', array(
        'name'  => $name,
        'color' => 'green',
    ));
```

... that is, use the name of the bundle.